# Why can't I ssh to a local (single-label) hostname: "ssh: connect to host myserver port 22: Invalid argument"?

Tags: router, ssh, arch-linux, dhcp, ipv6

(I figured out this is related to `nscd`; please see the bottom of the question)

I'm trying to connect to a headless server via my laptop; they share a wired link via a Linksys wireless router and TP-Link ethernet switch. I'm running Arch Linux on both machines, using a pretty default Systemd setup with dhcpcd for the network configuration.

After a recent system upgrade on the laptop, I started experiencing the following error when trying to ssh to the server (let's call it "myserver"):

```
$ ssh -v -v -F /dev/null myserver
OpenSSH_7.7p1, OpenSSL 1.1.0h  27 Mar 2018
debug1: Reading configuration data /dev/null
debug2: resolving "myserver" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to myserver [fe80::9cd8:b045:5974:c5cf] port 22.
debug1: connect to address fe80::9cd8:b045:5974:c5cf port 22: Invalid argument
ssh: connect to host myserver port 22: Invalid argument
```

Running the same command with `strace` shows the error comes from `connect`:

```
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(22), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "fe80::9cd8:b045:5974:c5cf", &sin6_addr), sin6_flowinfo=htonl(0), sin6_scope_id=0}, 28) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
```

However, `ping myserver` works fine:

```
$ ping myserver    
PING myserver(myserver (fe80::9cd8:b045:5974:c5cf)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from myserver (fe80::9cd8:b045:5974:c5cf%en0): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.533 ms
64 bytes from myserver (fe80::9cd8:b045:5974:c5cf%en0): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.549 ms
```

Usually I have a local `named` forwarding DNS queries but the error persists when I go back to using the router's DNS server directly:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by resolvconf
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

The error is intermittent: every few minutes I am able to connect successfully. When I can connect successfully, I see that `connect` is using an IPv4 address:

```
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(22), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.1.149")}, 16) = 0
```

However, the `host` command shows the same IPv4 address whether the connection is working or broken:

```
$ host myserver                   
myserver has address 192.168.1.149
```

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260003/connect-returns-invalid-argument-with-ipv6-address) question I thought to specify the interface manually (`ssh -v -v -F /dev/null -B en0 myserver`). This eliminates the error when it occurs, but it is not a permanent solution for me and it doesn't explain why the error suddenly appeared.

I used a `while` loop in my shell to determine the time to the nearest second when `ssh` goes from working to not working, and vice-versa, and I was not able to correlate these events with anything in the output of `journalctl`, including the `dhcpcd` messages.

I had originally posted this on Network Engineering, where host configuration turns out to be off-topic. On that site, user [Ricky Beam](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/users/619/ricky-beam) had posted a partial answer:

> Whatever is doing hostname resolution is returning link-local IPv6 address(es) that aren't valid for the interface selected -- i.e. "any". Link-local addresses must specify the interface -- eg. fe80:...:1%eth0
>
> Why you're getting a link-local address is unknown. Perhaps people familiar with Arch linux could provide further assistance.

---

Update: It seems to be a problem with `nscd` "name service cache daemon", which explains the intermittency I was experiencing (presumably having to do with cache expiry). It is fixed with:

```
sudo systemctl stop nscd.service
```

When I stop ncsd, then `ssh` is able to connect using a link-local address, but this time the `connect` call also specifies my primary interface "en0" and it succeeds:

```
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(22), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "fe80::9cd8:b045:5974:c5cf", &sin6_addr), sin6_flowinfo=htonl(0), sin6_scope_id=if_nametoindex("en0")}, 28) = 0
write(2, "debug1: Connection established.\r"..., 33) = 33
```

I guess the remaining question (which I could ask separately), is, is this a bug in nscd, and should I be using nscd at all?

Comment: The question is, why is your DNS returning a link-local IPv6 address for the name? This is a guaranteed path to misery and suffering. Use ULA or global addresses.

Comment: I don't know why my DNS is doing that, but I found a temporary fix in disabling `nscd`. And now I still get link-local addresses for local hosts, but `ssh` works. I updated the question... Any further insights are welcome.

Comment: Link local addresses are mainly for services on a LAN to discover each other, do autoconfiguration, etc. Relying on them for "normal" stuff like web browsing, ssh, etc., is generally considered a Bad Idea. Again, configure yourself a ULA prefix, or get global IPv6 connectivity, or both.

Comment: I don't know how to do those things. I didn't even know that my computers were using IPv6 until this came up.

Comment: The first will be a setting in your home router, if it's not a complete piece of ****. The second is something you need to yell at your ISP about.

Comment: I submitted a bug to glibc: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=23546

Answer (score 2):

When I brought a Raspberry Pi onto the network, this problem
manifested itself in a new way and I was able to finally diagnose it.

The problem is related to `systemd-resolved`. This has been affecting
other users, see for example Ask Ubuntu's [nslookup finds ip, but ping
doesnt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81797/nslookup-finds-ip-but-ping-doesnt)
or [systemd-resolved does not query dns server for local
domain](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917784/systemd-resolved-does-not-query-dns-server-for-local-domain).

I had assumed that `ssh myserver` would trigger a DNS lookup of
`myserver`. However, that is not the case on my system, here is the
default `nsswitch.conf`:

```
$ cat /etc/nsswitch.conf
# Name Service Switch configuration file.
# See nsswitch.conf(5) for details.
...
hosts: files mymachines myhostname resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns
...
```

The `resolve` component is `systemd-resolved`, which is a Lennart
Poettering project to implement the
[Zeroconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking)
protocols [Multicast DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS)
and [Link-Local Multicast Name
Resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-Local_Multicast_Name_Resolution).

The `[!UNAVAIL=return]` means that when `systemd-resolved` is
available, DNS host resolution is never used. Usually this is not a
problem because `systemd-resolved` is also able to create DNS queries.
However it apparently does not do this for single-label hostnames like
`myserver`, even when the DNS server is on my local router
(192.168.1.1). This is because it is reasoned that single-label
hostnames should not be exposed to the outside network, as explained
by Lennart in [this Github thread](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/2514).

This explains the fact that `host myserver` produced an IPv4 address
(from the router) while `ssh myserver` produced an IPv6 address (from
Multicast DNS or LLNR, not sure which).

I was confused by this because I never learned about Multicast DNS or
LLNR or IPv6. I never learned about these technologies because I
thought the familiar technologies of IPv4 and DNS were sufficient for
me.

Apparently `systemd-resolved` is necessary not just for producing
Zeroconf requests, but also for replying to them. The Raspberry Pi
which I brought onto my network had its `systemd-resolved` stopped for
some reason, so although I was able to look up the hostname with
`host` and `dig`, I was not able to see it via `ssh` or `ping`:

```
$ ping raspberrypi
ping: raspberrypi: Name or service not known
[2]$ host raspberrypi
raspberrypi has address 192.168.1.135
```

This led me to the first Ask Ubuntu bug report above, which led me to
the solution. If I start `systemd-resolved` on the Pi then I am able
to `ping` and `ssh` it. However, if I disable `systemd-resolved`
locally then I am also able to `ping` and `ssh` to the Pi.

For now I have just disabled `systemd-resolved` on all my systems,

```
$ sudo systemctl stop systemd-resolved.service
$ sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved.service
```

since it seems to create problems with GNU libc's `nscd` and since it
requires me to learn about technologies like IPv6, mDNS, and LLNR,
which I don't currently need - because my computers are all connected
to a basic consumer router which provides familiar technologies of DNS
and NAT out-of-the-box.

Thanks to those who commented on my original question, but in the end
it was not necessary to "configure yourself a ULA prefix, or get
global IPv6 connectivity, or both" via "a setting in your home router,
if it's not a complete piece of ****" or "to yell at your ISP". I just
had to disable some of Lennart's new software to take myself away from
the bleeding edge. The Github thread has some discussion about whether
the software is actually behaving correctly, but I find myself in the
same position as many other users: after spending hours of time
figuring out that `systemd-resolved` is the culprit, I'd rather not
spend more hours trying to understand how to fix it, when disabling is
so easy.

Comment: You probably won't ever need LLMNR or mDNS. You _will_ need IPv6. IPv4 is dying a slow painful death. That said, systemd-resolved is AFAIK another piece of ****.

Comment: Poor Lennart. I just wanted to say that I enjoyed using his useful (to me) Systemd to disable his not-so-useful (to me) systemd-resolved.